# SQLite - Count how many records there are for each foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, count, analysis

- I need a query that counts the primary keys that were not assigned in the foreign key. In short: with the count value of 0 when not appearing in the foreign key. See image: 
  [image: text]
- My query returns only the count of the primary keys that have become foreign key in another table. My query does not show the values ​​0.

I'm using:

```
SELECT l.name AS listName, COUNT(p.fk_list_identifier) AS countNum
FROM list AS l INNER JOIN person AS p 
WHERE l.identifier = p.fk_list_identifier
GROUP BY l.name;
```

Comment: Change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the lists with no reference, you can do:

```
SELECT l.name AS listName
FROM list l LEFT JOIN
     person AS p 
     on l.identifier = p.fk_list_identifier
WHERE p.fk_list_identifier IS NULL
GROUP BY l.name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot. Good night. *-*

Comment: How do I add the condition to filter by **l.name** using the **LIKE** clause, this same query? I want to count where the FK is null and have filtered by **l.name LIKE ?**. I tried but failed.